# Is there a data structure with both ArrayList and Map-like properties?

Tags: java, arrays, dictionary, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have a series of data, and every other value is paired with the value before it.

2  3  5  6  8  9  12  5 
where for example the 2 would be written out with the 3 and the 5 written out with the 6 (as exponents, but that's not really relevant).

I'm never certain how many values will be in the line, so I want to use an ArrayList, but I need them to be linked. I want the 2 to be associated with the 3 in the style of a 2D array.

I can't use a map because they keys will likely repeat all over the place so there won't be any unique characteristics about the key/value associations. I just need an expandable 2D array and i'm not sure I can get that from a HashMap, ArrayList, 2D array or any other data structure i'm aware of.

any pointers?

EDIT:
To clarify, this will represent 2 ^ 3  5 ^6   8 ^ 9 etc. and I will want to eventually print that in a readable form, and I'll also need to sort by highest exponent values. So I need to have some control over the order in which they go into the data structure.

Comment: What's the highest exponent that you expect to represent? Are all exponents integer?

Comment: yes all exponents are integers and i suppose it could go really high, but i wouldn't assume more than 20

Comment: Can you use an array of 21 numbers, one number per exponent? Exponents that are unused would have zero in that array, so you wouldn't print them.

Comment: Is it important to maintain the order of the pairs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not create a class to hold both numbers together? Then you can use a `List<Pair>` to hold all of your data.

```
public class Pair {
    private final int a;
    private final int b;

    public Pair(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return b;
    }
}
```

/e

Since you need to sort, you could either make `Pair` implement [`Comparable<Pair>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html), or create a [`Comparator<Pair>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) so you can use [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) to organize your data.

Comment: i was commenting about comparator and you added xD +1

Answer (score 0):

Construct an `ArrayList<Integer[]>`, where every `Integer[]` will have length 2. The `ArrayList`'s expandable, and allows access to a pair's elements with `.get(index1)[index2]`.

Comment: can you then sort the ArrayList by one of the two values within Integer[]?

Comment: Yes; use `Collections.sort` (as @Jeffrey mentioned). 
`Collections.sort(yourArrayList, new Comparator<Integer[]>(){
  public int compare(Integer[] a, Integer[] b) {
   return a[indOfExponent]-b[indOfExponent]; //or b[indOfExponent] - a[indOfExponent]
  }                        
 });`        Ed: Forgive the formatting; c+p code into an editor.

Answer (score 0):

If the order isn't important you could have a map of lists, where the map key is the base and each item in the list is one of the exponents the base is raised to.

So for example, if you line looked like:

```
1 2 1 3 2 4 2 5 3 6
```

The map would look like:

```
{ 1 -> [2, 3], 2 -> [4, 5], 3 -> [6] }
```